# What's the difference between p ::first-letter and p::first-letter?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

What's the difference between `p ::first-letter` and `p::first-letter`?

`p::first-letter` can successfully select the first letter inside a paragraph, but `p ::first-letter` cannot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The selector `p::first-letter` selects the first letter inside the `p` whereas the `p ::first-letter` selects the first letter within the child elements of the `p`.

`p ::first-letter` is equivalent to `p *::first-letter`. The below is what the [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) say:

> If a universal selector represented by * (i.e. without a namespace prefix) is not the only component of a sequence of simple selectors selectors or is immediately followed by a pseudo-element, then the * may be omitted and the universal selector's presence implied.

**Note:** Even though the selector (`p ::first-letter`) itself points to the first letter inside all child elements, the `::first-letter` selector works only on block or inline-block elements and hence wouldn't work on a `span` unless its `display` is modified.

```css
p ::first-letter {
  color: red;
}
p::first-letter {
  color: blue;
}

span{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>Some text <span>inside a span</span> and <span>inside this span too</span>
</p>
```

Comment: You really should be closing these as duplicates. :)

Comment: @Paulie_D Got web-tiki to hammer it. I've left my answer as-is because a few of us felt my answer has more information.

Comment: S'fine by me...I've cleaned up my comments...you might want to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

`p ::first-letter` means change the style of the first letter of any element which is a descendant of p. Whereas `p::first-letter` means change the first letter of the p element.

Comment: Not true. The space indicates that the selector is a [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) (i.e. select the first letter of all children, grandchildren, etc. elements within the `p` tag)...

Comment: I stand corrected. I have modified my answer.